# Why gulp-inject comment was removed when I minify HTML with gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

Here is to minify html file inside gulp as follow

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var path = require('path');
var rename = require('gulp-rename'); 
var uglify = require('gulp-uglifyes');
var mainBowerFiles = require('gulp-main-bower-files');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var gulpFilter = require('gulp-filter');
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
var del = require('del');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var pagespeed = require('psi');
var reload = browserSync.reload;
var fs = require('fs');
var inject = require('gulp-inject');

gulp.task('html', function() {
  var assets = $.useref.assets({searchPath: '{.tmp,app}'});

  return gulp.src('app/**/**/*.html')
    .pipe(assets)
    // Remove Any Unused CSS
    // Note: If not using the Style Guide, you can delete it from
    // the next line to only include styles your project uses.
    .pipe($.if('*.css', $.uncss({
      html: [
        'app/index.html'
      ],
      // CSS Selectors for UnCSS to ignore
      ignore: []
    })))

    // Concatenate And Minify Styles
    // In case you are still using useref build blocks
    .pipe($.if('*.css', $.csso()))
    .pipe(assets.restore())
    .pipe($.useref())
    // Minify Any HTML
    .pipe($.if('*.html', $.minifyHtml()))
    // Output Files
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
    .pipe($.size({title: 'html'}));
});
```

after minify and moved to production folder, all of `gulp-inject` comment gone.

```
<!-- inject:js -->
<!-- endinject -->
```

Please let me know how to solve it.

Comment: @Mark using `gulp` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which plugin are you using? Gulp-minify-html?  That is deprecated.  If you are using that try the option "comments: true" as in :

```
.pipe($.if('*.html', $.minifyHtml({comments:true})))
```

Comment: using `gulp` only.

Comment: Well, you are using various plugins, gulp-if, gulp-csso, etc.  Do you have a statement like var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')(); at the top of your gulpfile.js?

Comment: I've edited my question as using plugins inside `gulp` file. Please take a look. Thanks,

Comment: OK.  The gulp-load-plugin allows you to use more plugins than are actually listed there as "requires".  It is able to find them in your node_modules directory and import them.  One of them is presumably gulp-minify-html which must have been installed on your machine at some point.  Did you try my suggested fix in the answer above?  Change that one line.